ffmpeg input -ss accuracy
As from FFmpeg version 2.1, -ss used as an input option should be frame accurate (when transcoding, not stream-copying).
I tried it with different versions of FFmpeg, up to recent ones, and with MPEG-TS files doesn't look accurate to me. I still get the cut (or the frame extraction) at the first I-frame after the specified timestamp.
Is it an exception for MPEG-TS files, or am I missing something?

MPEG-TS don't have a global keyframe index ,so even input -ss will seek to the next KF after the ss timestamp.
Add -copyts -start_at_zero and seek to a few seconds earlier. Then add a trim filter with the exact timestamp.

tnx gyan,
more or less understood. I'll have to try.
problem started with recent versions of ffmpeg (5.1 & above); up to version 4.3 to extract a frame at exact timestamp, without waiting log time for output -ss seeking, I finally found that combining input -ss (up to at least before the previous keyframe) and adding output -ss up to the desired timestamp was correct IF TS file had only video track, otherwise was shifted by the difference between video_track start_time and earliest starting audio-track; calculating that difference with ffprobe and adding to output -ss gave the correct frame.
with recent versions behaviour is different: if video-only TS file, than it's easy (no shift, and sum of the two -ss), but with audio-video files looks like it's initially reaching the first KF after input -ss, than if output -ss is less than input -ss returns that KF, otherwise if larger it returns the frame at output -ss timestamp (from beginning of file).
so old procedure cannot be applied anymore.
I will deep study what you suggested.
thanks
